# Regex in Python to get the subject text from an email

Tags: python, regex

I have multiple emails as text files and I have to extract the email's subject using regex

> Subject: Meet the new Customer Support Representative
>
> Dear team,
>
> I am pleased to introduce you to [Name] who is starting today as a
> Customer Support Representative. She will be providing technical
> support and assistance to our users, ensuring they enjoy the best
> experience with our products.
>
> Feel free to greet [Name] in person and congratulate her on the new
> role!
>
> Best regards, [Your name] [Job title]

To extract the subject line from this sample email text, I tried using this regex:  `r"(?m)^Subject: (.+)$"` 
 The output I got is:

**Meet the new Customer Support Representative**

But the output that I require is:

**Subject: Meet the new Customer Support Representative**

How can I modify this regex to get the "Subject:" part too?

Comment: You already have it, but you are seeing the capture group 1 value. You can just omit the capture group. `(?m)^Subject: .+$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should put ’Subject: ’ into the second capture group like `r"(?m)^(Subject: .+)$"` and use this value.

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(?m)^(Subject: .+)$")
match = pattern.match(text)
if match:
    result = match.group(2)
```